wso2 apim integration with entra_id user not authorized error
I using this guido to make the integration: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-azure-ad-key-manager/
but when i access to devportal to create the app and subscribe the apis in the generate keys step get an error like this "User is not authorized".
And cannot create the token for test my API.
My app is deploy over Kubernetes with 4.3 version
I change configuration, try postman and on postman the same credentials ar actually working, in the scope management endpoint y put this value : api://048ded36-de94-42d9-848c-6a4aa345/ ; because this value is not present.
There is the error on pod:
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.                                                                                   ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException_aroundBody82(APIUtil.java:1678) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]                                                         ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]                                                                         ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:182) ~[org.w ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.api ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) ~[org.wso ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimg ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9. ││ wso2am     ... 60 more                                                                                                                                                                                        ││ wso2am Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Invalid client secret provided, Please try again                                                                                         ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.azure.client.TokenGenerator.getAccessToken(TokenGenerator.java:58) ~[azure.key.manager_1.0.9.jar:?]                                                                                    ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.azure.client.TokenGenerator.getAccessTokenInfo(TokenGenerator.java:69) ~[azure.key.manager_1.0.9.jar:?]                                                                                ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.azure.client.AzureADClient.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AzureADClient.java:254) ~[azure.key.manager_1.0.9.jar:?]                                                                       ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:171) ~[org.w ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.api ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) ~[org.wso ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimg ││ wso2am     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9. ││ wso2am     ... 60 more
Please help me.
greetings

From the provided log i could see this. Seems like the provided client secret when configuring the keymanger in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-azure-ad-key-manager/#:~:text=Provide%20the%20relevant%20details%20in%20the%20Connector%20Configurations%20section is not correct
wso2am Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Invalid client secret provided, Please try again       


thaks, for teh quickly replay, but the i test the secret in postman and it works, now i upload the ssl certificates to wso2carbon.jks to test if is a problem of security also
